# Incompatibilidad de navegadores de web diseñada en bootstrap

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Tengo una web diseñada en bootstrap. Al abrir la página en chrome funciona correctamente. Pero con internet explorer, nada que ver. Cómo consigo mantener los colores de los textos y los colores de las tablas igual? Gracias

Comment: Muéstranos el código, o al menos el enlace que podamos visitar la web para ver el código. ¿Qué versión de IE usas? - Si no pones más información te cerrarán la pregunta como demasiada amplia.

Comment: Hola Miaweb, bienvenida. Pasate por el [Tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona este sitio. Como dice @MarcLemien, has de añadir el codigo para ver que puede estar fallando. La pregunta actual es muy amplia. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias a los dos. El código es éste: 
<li style="color: #FF8F41"><span class="glyphicon"> <img src="{{ asset('imagenes/phone.png') }}" width="20px" height="20px" /></span> 900 900 900</li>
En Chrome, el número de teléfono aparece en naranja, como debe ser. Pero en IE no coge ese color y aparece azul y subrayado. Gracias

Comment: Por favor, crea un [mcve] y comparte el código generado. Puede que también sea conveniente añadir algo de código alrededor de lo que comentas (¿hay algún `a`?)

Answer (score 0):

Saludos  miaweb,

No comprendo bien la pregunta pero lo que puedo entender es que tienes un codigo css que no se te renderiza correctamente en varios navegadores...
Recuerda que no todos los navegadores soportan css3 en su totalidad, por ello debes hacer uso de los prefijos.
Te dejo un enlace muy bueno en donde podras comprobar el soporte para cada navegador [1](https://caniuse.com/) . Por otro lado, los prefijos que se usan son:

-webkit- (Google Chrome y Safari)
-moz- (Firefox)
-o- (Opera)
-ms- (Internet explorer)

Espero te sea de ayuda mi respuesta, de no serlo, hazlo saber y aclara un poco mejor tu pregunta para ser mas certero con las respuestas.

Comment: Aunque estos consejos pueden ser de ayuda al usuario, son genéricos y parecen más un comentario que una respuesta a la pregunta. Sería mejor esperar a que se edite la pregunta, para tener todos los detalles y poder responder de manera concreta.

Comment: Tal y como te comenta @AlvaroMontoro, tu respuesta debería ser un comentario. Echa un vistazo a [esta respuesta en meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/959/18608).